# How to get search key when someone edit the result after search

Tags: php, codeigniter, search

In my project there is list of some records. User can search the records by project name. After search user can edit particular record. After edit when user click on Update button right now it is redirecting to list page but the search result gone and all records are displaying.

After Update i want to display the searched records only not all. How to get search key back ? I dont want to use session for that if any other better way.

I am using codeigniter.

**For example:**

There is a list of 10 records. User search the records by "ABC". Result come which has "ABC" project like 5 records come. Then user edit one record and update it. After update I wan to display that 5 records with search key "ABC" only. Right now it is displaying 10( ALL) records because i am redirecting on list page without search key. I have no idea how to do it. :(

Comment: Add some code or create a demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i would do personally is something like this on my list Page i would have a form which would be submitted to search function through **GET** method. This way i would have all my search Params in the URL and my URL would be something like this :

`exampledomain.com/users?name=steve&age=23`

Now for the edit page i would generate a link with a special parameter say : **lastpage** whose value would be some encoded form of the current search params. So when the user would go to the edit page the URL would be somthing like this:

`exampledomain.com/users/edit/34?lastpage=erasc1235234safvdadsrgdfgbvcdfgrt435`

when the edit functunality is completed. I would pick this lastpage Param form `$_GET['lastpage']` ( or in CI you can use `$this->input->get('lastpage')`)  to get the encoded value of lastpage and decode that to get all the previous URL search Params. and redirect the user to the serach function again with the search params attached to the URL.

Comment: Thanks bro.. But i can not use GET method for some reason. I am using post method any idea in post ?

Comment: well another method would be to save the search param's in cookies as string. that way you could always get the value of the `last_page` cookie variable and redirect user to the previous page.

Comment: I think you need to save your variable somewhere. how about putting you variable in a temporary hidden input ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the keyword that has been type. You have three options

- Save keyword as GET variable
- Save keyword as hidden input
- Save keyword as SESSION variable
- Save keyword as COOKIEvariable

Since that you don't to choose the option 3 and 4. Your only option is to create a GET variable.Just add `domain.com/controller/function?keyword=ABC`and get that on controller as `rldecode($_GET['keyword']);` or create hidden input where you can save you value and fetch that value.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem i had with dividing the view to two types

1) the normal view which shows all records and

2) the other view which shows all recently searched records for the last searched key.

To achieve this u need to store the searched records' ids and place from which the records have been taken to be stored in a temporary DB Table like TableforSearch and store the search key like 'ABC' in session.

On search of the Key 'ABC' find the ids of the records which matches the Key and save it to Table TableforSearch along with the Search Key and UserId.

Then use the Session to get the Key and search the table with the Key in Session to fetch the row that has All the Ids of the Searched Key.
For Error Handling see if the Ids present in Table have not been deleted for that Record.

And finally on Showing of searched items Show the second Page , for the other show normal first page

Answer (score -1):

One way around is that, when user searches anything in list page (I hope your list page and search page are the same) than every time on new search, store the search keywords in `localStorage` and when user updates the record than redirect to list page along with your search keywords from `localStorage`. (This is suggested only if your list page and search page are the same. i.e. you handle the search with some parameters passed to list page.)

Comment: yes my search and list page are same. localstorage means in database ?

Comment: No, its `HTML5 localStorage`. You can handle it using javascript. [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: ok thanks its new thing for me. Can we store multiple value in localstorage?

Comment: nice concept but when i edit one record it in edit page. Then when i click on 'update' button it is redirecting on list page and i am getting null in localstorage.

Comment: You have to pass the keywords in the link of update button.

Answer (score -1):

save your search criteria in a session variable `$_SESSION['mysearch'] = 'ABC'` and use it when redirecting `header("Location: /mysearch.php?criteria=" . urlencode($_SESSION['mysearch']))`.
Then in your "mysearch.php" you would `ureldecode($_GET['criteria'])`, run the search again and present the results.

Comment: He said that he do not want to use session

Comment: No, he said he doesn;t want to use session if any other better way. this is just your opinion not a thing you can rely as true.